# How to optimize knex migration?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

i'm working on a project that has been using bookshelfjs (with knexjs migration system) since its beginning (1 year and a half).
We now have a little bit less than 80 migrations and it's starting to take a lot of time (more than 2 minutes) to run all migrations. We are deploying using continuous integration so the migrations have to be run in the test process and in the deployment process.

I'd like to know how to optimize that. Is that possible to start from a clean state ? I don't care about losing rollback possibilities. The project is much more mature right now and we don't need to iterate much anymore on the data structure part.

Is there any best practice ? I'm coming from the Doctrine (PHP) world and it's really different.

Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create database dump from your current database state.
2. Always use that dump to initialize new database for tests
3. Run migrations on top of already initialized database

In that way migration system applies only newly added migrations to top of existing initial dump.

Answer (score 0):

When using `knex.schema.createTable` to create table with foregin keys from another table, and later when you run `knex migrate:latest`, the table with foreign keys should be processed before the one using the foreign keys. For example, table1 has foreign key `key1` from talbe2, to make sure table2 is processed first, you can add numbers before the name of the table. Then in your migrations folder, there will be `1table2.js`, `2table1.js`. This looks hacky and not pretty, but it works!